# On hover fadeToggle with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have some divs with an img inside. Above the img is a div that is hidden, but will appear on hover of the img.  I know how to make it work, but I want it to be simpler, this is more for my own learning. I want it to work the same as I have, just simpler and cleaner jquery/javascript.

```
$('#img-1').hover(function(){
    $('#overlay-1').stop().fadeToggle(400);
});
$('#img-2').hover(function(){
  $('#overlay-2').stop().fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Here is it in action: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfhfzha9/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('.img').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop().fadeToggle(400);
 });
```

the $(this) keyword is the object that you're calling hover() on.  So we find() children of the thing that was hovered with the class .overlay

Comment: this works great with the classes, any reason it wont work the same with IDs?

Comment: @jiroscopes Ids are meant to be unique.  You can't/shouldn't use the same id more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS, using `:hover` on `.img` and `transition` with `opacity` on `.overlay`

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
}
.img > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: #f7c845;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
.overlay > p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #212121;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
.img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img" id="img-1">
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay-1">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/4e/40/bf4e4067252227bd3f758bba7dcee2ff.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="img" id="img-2">
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay-2">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/4e/40/bf4e4067252227bd3f758bba7dcee2ff.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: I know I can do it with CSS, but I am looking to find the answer in Jquery for learning purposes. Thank you!